# PHP String Replacement

Tags: php

I wish to have one string that contains for instance (mystring):

file config.php

```
$mystring = "hello my name is $name and i got to $school";
```

file index.php

```
include('config.php');

$name = $_GET['name'];
$school = $_GET['school'];

echo $mystring;
```

Would this work ? or are there any better ways

Answer (score 5):

```
$string = 'Hello, my name is %s and I go to %s';
printf($string, $_GET['name'], $_GET['school']);
```

or

```
$string = 'Hello, my name is :name and I go to :school';
echo str_replace(array(':name', ':school'), array($_GET['name'], $_GET['school']), $string);
```

You can automate that last one with something like:

```
function value_replace($values, $string) {
    return str_replace(array_map(function ($v) { return ":$v"; }, array_keys($values)), $values, $string);
}

$string = 'Hello, my name is :name and I go to :school';
echo values_replace($_GET, $string);
```

Comment: Good answer except for the name of your function `values_replace` :D underscore in the name functions are deprectated since 1990 :D

Comment: @yes123: No (at least not in PHP). Don't mix up functions with methods ;) [/offtopic]

Comment: @yes That entirely depends on which of PHP's naming standards you're following. Feel free to rename your version of this function. You're not going to just copy and paste it anyway, right? **Right?!** ;P

Comment: @deceze: Actually i am not going to copy/paste anything here :D

Comment: @KingCrunch: your point could be good (underscore for functions, camelCase for methods) but still i prefer everything in camelCase. Like this you can easly recognize if a function is a php-built-in or user-made

Answer (score 3):

No it won't work.

You have to define `$name` first before using it in another variable

config.php should look like

```
<?php
$name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']);
$school = htmlspecialchars($_GET['school']);
$mystring = "hello my name is $name and i got to $school";
```

and index.php like

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
echo $mystring;
```

Why didn't you try it?

demo:
http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/2d9e0.php?name=martin&school=fr.kupky

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) like this:

```
$mystring = "hello my name is %s and i got to %s";
// ...
printf($mystring, $name, $school);
```

Answer (score -4):

This works because your $mystring literal is using double quotes, if you'd used single quotes then it would not work.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: It does, because $mystring is defined before $name and $school are defined, and PHP replaces the values at time of definition, not at the time of output.

Comment: Sure but I was just making the distinction between " and '